# libstdc++ as a dependency

Tags: c++, debian, packaging, libstdc++

I'm packaging a library for distrbution in Ubuntu's ppa (personal packaging repo) system.

I have in my debian/control these lines:

> Build-Depends: build-essential, libc6-dev, yasm, cmake, pkg-config, swig, libglew-dev, mesa-common-dev, libstdc++-5-dev, python3-dev, python3-numpy, libasound2-dev
>   ...
>
> Depends: python3, mesa-utils, libstdc++5, glew-utils, python3-numpy, v4l-utils, python3-pip

But now, after using the command "ldd" on my shared library, I get this:

> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f31e93f6000)

So, the questions are:

- Am I supposed to add a dependency to libstdc++N (N is a number) in my debian package at all?
- ..or is there some metapackage (say, just "libstdc++") that automatically selects the correct libstdc++N for the system

I sort of solved this for the build dependency and libstdc++6-dev.  The dependencies seem to be

> build-essential => g++ => g++-7 => libstdc++-7-dev

(although that's 7, not 6..?)

I'm using C++14 standards.  Does that correlate with the libstdc++ version?